# Raw json field type in hive

Tags: json, hadoop, hive

How can I define table in hive with raw json field (no parsing, as a plain text)?

For the following s3 file:

```
{"first_field":1, "json_field": {"a":{"b":"c"}, "d":"e"}, "sec_field":4}
{"first_field":2, "json_field": {"m":"cv", "d":"e"}, "sec_field":5}
{"first_field":3, "json_field": {"k":1, "d":"e"}, "sec_field":6}
```

I wish that the following query:

```
select first_field, json_field, sec_field from web.json_table;
```

Will return:

```
1   {"a":{"b":"c"}, "d":"e"}    4
2   {"m":"cv", "d":"e"}         5
3   {"k":1, "d":"e"}            6
```

I tried to define the tables as follow:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE web.json_table(
first_field integer,
json_field string,
sec_field integer
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
location 's3n://my-bucket';
```

but the query return:

```
hive> select first_field, json_field, sec_field from web.json_table;
OK
1   {   NULL
2   {   NULL
3   {   NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I think You can't have a generic way to map any JSON in a string.

You need defined your `json_field` as **fixed** Struct:

```
{"a":{"b":"c"}, "d":"e"} ==> STRUCT<a:STRUCT<b:STRING>,d:STRING>

{"m":"cv", "d":"e"} ==> STRUCT<m:STRING,d:STRING>

{"k":1, "d":"e"} ==> STRUCT<k:STRING,d:STRING>
```

for your actual JSON :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE web.json_table (
    first_field integer,
    json_field STRUCT<a:STRUCT<b:STRING>,d:STRING,m:STRING,k:STRING>,
    sec_field integer
) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
location 's3n://my-bucket';
```

Warning : old Hive version doesn't support upper case in JSON Key.

**EDIT :**

1. Create an external CSV table `ext_table` with a single `json_data` columns as string (use a special separator which doesn'nt apppear, ex `0x00` or `0x01`)
2. Create view using `get_json_object` based an previous table `ext_table` to extract all your fixed and dynamic fields

Comment: yes, I am aware to that option, but it not what I wish for.
Since my nested json in not predictable.
I wish to have the ability to such query using presto:
select get_json_object(json_field, "$.a") from web.json_table;